# How can I run a CMD command in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to run a simple dos command with jenkins

```
  stage('test cmd shell') {
         steps {
            echo 'execute cmd ...'
            bat label: '', script: 'ipconfig  -all'
         }
    }
```

But id dosen't work.
This error shows up every time: 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Does someone now how to fix this?

Comment: bat "ipconfig -all" should work

Comment: Script works for me. Maybe `ComSpec` environment variable is not set correctly. Check Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > System Information. Value of `ComSpec` should look like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thank You. I fixed it with this line: PATH = 'PATH' + ';c:\\Windows\\System32'